# Is it possible to use two separate event handler functions on the server side?

Tags: python, flask, flask-socketio

In the supplied source code,

1. The client-side has two event-handlers: `connect` and `server_to_client`. When the page loads for the first time, the `connect` emits texts: `hello!` and `world!`.
2. Then, on the server side, the function `server_to_client()` received this message, prints it on the console, and subsequently emits another message `received from the server` to the client.
3. Finally, on the client side, the event-handler `server_to_client` prints the server side message to an H2-tag.

As you can see, two functions are working at the client side, and only one function is working at the server side.

---

**On the server side**, the same function is handling `client_to_server` event and raising `server_to_client` event.

Say, I want to use two different functions on the server side. I.e. one function will print `hello! world!`, and a different function will emit `received from the server` to the client.

Is it possible?

---

**server_sends_client_receives.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Long task</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.5.4/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
         $(document).on('click', '.widget input', function (event) {
            namespace = '/test';
            var socket = io(namespace);

            socket.on('connect', function() {
                $('#messages').append('<br/>' + $('<div/>').text('Requesting task to run').html());
                ////myText = $("messages").text()
                socket.emit('client_to_server',    {'hello': 'hello!', 'world': 'world!'});
            });

            socket.on('server_to_client', function(msg, cb) {
                $('#messages').text(msg.data);
                if (cb)
                    cb();
            });

            event.preventDefault();
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="widget">
        <input type="submit" value="Click me" />
    </div>
    <h3>Messages</h3>
    <H2 id="messages" >xxx yyy zzz</H2>
</body>
</html>
```

**server_sends_client_receives.py**

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, emit, disconnect
from time import sleep

async_mode = None

app = Flask(__name__)

socketio_obj = SocketIO(app, async_mode=async_mode)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('server_sends_client_receives.html',
                           sync_mode=socketio_obj.async_mode)


@socketio_obj.on('client_to_server', namespace='/test')
def server_to_client(arg1):
    try:
        print('received from the client : ', arg1['hello'])
        print('received from the client : ', arg1['world'])
        emit('server_to_client', {'data': 'received from the server'})
        disconnect()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio_obj.run(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the [`disconnect()`](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#flask_socketio.disconnect) call, which terminates the connection with the client.

Define a separate handler that listens to `'client_to_server2'` event:

```py
@socketio_obj.on('client_to_server', namespace='/test')
def server_to_client(arg1):
    try:
        print('received from the client : ', arg1['hello'])
        print('received from the client : ', arg1['world'])
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)


@socketio_obj.on('client_to_server2', namespace='/test')
def server_to_client2():
    try:
        emit('server_to_client', {'data': 'received from the server'})
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```

Emit `'client_to_server2'` event from client:

```js
socket.emit('client_to_server', {'hello': 'hello!', 'world': 'world!'});
socket.emit('client_to_server2');
```